# How to determine concentration limits of a buffer that's limited by solubility?

Tags: physical-chemistry, solubility, ph, concentration

I need to maintain a certain range of % of ionisation from a buffer.

For e.g. Histidine buffer. When making high concentration of this buffer at (say) pH 7.2, 25'C, [concentration] is limited to 75mM solution (250mL), due to the solubility. Adding HCl increases solubility just as much, but it also decreases pH of the solution.

I want to know if there's a calculation or a formula to figure out the concentration limits (at least the highest concentration) of a particular buffer one can plan to make instead of trial and error in the lab?

Comment: @Martin - マーチン even giving a bounty, I did not get an answer or response to my previous questions. I just wonder if there's anyway to receive community attention and support?

Comment: bon, you can only ping someone in a comment if they're the author or an editor of that particular post. You would need to ping Mart in chat, for him to get a notification. As to not getting an answer, the site's seen a significant uptick in the number of questions posted lately, and a ***lot*** of questions are getting overlooked. Asking specifically for assistance, in chat or in a comment as you did, is probably your best bet.

Comment: @hBy2Py oh yeah that's good to know. well do you have any advice for finding a solution to my question? it doesn't have to be Mart.

Comment: I've been thinking about this on and off -- I can sort of piece together a general approach, but solubility of mixed solutions, especially ~concentrated ones, can get kind of complicated and it's always system-dependent.